# How can I learn one of the standard English accents?

Tags: british-english, american-accent, accent

A few months ago, I was asked to send a videotape of my self-introduction for a job of a language teacher in China. I was rejected citing the reason that my accent was not satisfactory.

I want to train myself in either American or British Posh accent.

How can I get started with?

Comment: You could look for a local club or class where English is spoken.  See if you can find some ex-pats and see if someone would be willing to teach you; sometimes people who are working in your country have spouses that are technically not allowed to work, and one of them might be willing to help. Watch English movies  and TV, or take a class.

Comment: What is your native language/accent?

Comment: @user3169, Indian.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because "How can I improve my English?" type questions are [off-topic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question on local accents

Comment: This may give some perspective on what you are facing: https://www.quora.com/Why-do-Indians-usually-speak-English-with-such-a-strong-accent-Is-English-pronunciation-so-unfamiliar-compared-to-the-spoken-languages-in-India

Answer (score 1):

**Travel** is often one of the best ways to improve your skills in a foreign language. Can you spend time in England or the United States? "Total immersion" in the language (being surrounded by native and fluent speakers at all times) can be one of the most effective ways to build memory (and muscle memory) of a new language.

Travel is very expensive, though, and requires time off from work or school. Another good option is consuming lots of **media** in the target language. Movies, TV, and radio will give you a range of accents and styles to choose from. Watch and listen to them frequently.

Try watching a short BBC news report (for example), and then filming yourself giving the same report. Listen to the recording of yourself and compare it to the BBC newscaster's report. Try to pick out the differences between your accent and the newscaster's. Then, do your recording again. Is it closer to the native speaker's?

This takes time and effort. It's a matter of habit and muscle memory, so repetition will be very important in improving these skills.